# Is there a way to put a static enum on a class?

Tags: typescript

I am currently writing a class that I would like to bundle with an enumerator.

example code:

```
class MyClass {
    static enum MyType {
        State1, State2, State3
    };
}
```

This way when I have some method foo I can define it as follows:

```
function CreateMyClass(type: MyClass.MyType) {
   ...
}
```

Perhaps I do not have the syntax correct (or maybe I'm going about this in the wrong way)? Is this possible, or is there a workaround so that I do not have to create an interface for a static variable in order to accept the enum type in a method parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't define the enum within the class, but you can add it elsewhere and use it within the class.

```
enum MyType {
    State1, State2, State3
};

class MyClass {
    constructor(private type: MyType) {

    }
}

var myInstance = new MyClass(MyType.State2);
```

Answer (score 1):

What about module?

```
module M {
    export enum MyType {
        State1, State2, State3
    };

    export class MyClass {
        constructor(param: string) {
            alert(param);
        }
    }
}

function CreateMyClass(type: M.MyType): M.MyClass {
    if (type === M.MyType.State1)
        return new M.MyClass("Hi!");
    else
        return new M.MyClass("Hello!");
}
```